# How to recognize a datatable as a part of another datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

How to do this :

I have two `datatables` :

> FIRST : `DT_All` ---> composed of : `emp_num` ,....other columns
>
> SECOND :`DT_Part`--->composed of one column as a key `emp_num`

---

where `DT_part` may be part of `DT_ALL` or not exist in this datatable .

If it was a part of `DT_All`

I want a way to recognize them in the `DT_ALL` .How to do this in easy and fast way ?

---

Example :

`DT_All`

```
 emp_num  column1  column2  column3

  227      7        33.3     ss

  155      5        10.7     mm

  122      5        1.66     aa

  678      2        8.9      rr

  555      1        1.11     aa
```

---

`DT_part` :

```
   emp_num 

   155

   678
```

I want  output like this:

```
 emp_num  column1  column2  column3   flag

  227      7        33.3     ss        0

  155      5        10.7     mm        1

  122      5        1.66     aa        0

  678      2        8.9      rr        1

  555      1        1.11     aa        0
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input\output to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `left join` on both tables like this:-

```
var result = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
             on t1.Field<int>("emp_num") equals t2.Field<int>("emp_num") into g
             from foo in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 emp_num = t1.Field<int>("emp_num"),
                 col1 = t1.Field<string>("col1"),
                 flag = foo != null ? 1 : 0
              };
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WUnpMu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` operator. Pseudo Code below(not tested, some typos might be made):

```
var items = DT_All
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => DT_Part.Field<string>("emp_num").Contains(x.EmpNum));
```

Comment: i want to recognize them in the same datatable `DT_All` not as a result

Comment: Ok, then describe what do You mean by "recognize them in the same datatable"

Comment: i mean when watching the `DT_ALL` itself  ican recognize the intersection by flag or some otherway

Comment: Hmm Maybe add a column with this flag and populate it while getting data for DataTables